# How to figure out missing includes for gradle 'implementation'?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, teamcity, build.gradle

I use an internal library (lib) in my Android app (app).

On my local machine both

```
api 'com.example.lib:1.2.3'
```

and

```
implement 'com.example.lib:1.2.3'
```

is working and building. but on TeamCity `api` works but implementation can not find:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get
>   resource
>   'http://example.bintray.com/android/com/example/lib/1.2.3/lib-1.2.3.aar'.

**How can I find out the missing transitive include for that? How can I fix that using `implementation`?**